# Почему сам по себе отключается ноутбук?

Tags: ubuntu

На ноуте HP Probook 4330S, установлены win 7 максимальная и в качестве 2-й  ОС Ubuntu (11-04, natty, gnome). Проблема в том, что иногда, в день 2-3 раза, ноут, когда работаю на линуксе, само собой отключается. Именно когда уйдет в спящий режим, нажимаю клаву, или мышку, пытается выйти с ждущего режима, и - вабах - отключается. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключите спящий режим или попробуйте в биосе соотв. опции изменить.

Comment: ок.Спасибо.А если я обновлю систему, так как убунту предлогает апгрейдит, не измениться ситуация?

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости, не хватает напряжения для выхода из спящего режима.  Проверьте вольтаж - скиньте конфигурацию ноута. Как ядро прогружает процессор? - Нужно снять логи с загрузки процессора.

[[@e_klimin](/users/370/e_klimin)](/users/370/e_klimin):

> Отключите спящий режим или попробуйте в биосе соотв. опции изменить.

Согласен: Изменить опции напряжения.

Answer (score 0):

ACPI отключай причем делается это ручками в конфигах, гугл в помощь